# Screen manager: screen change does not work

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to change screen with screen manager on on_release event, but when nothing happens when button is pressed. 
Here is python code:

```
class Information(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SlothFacts(Screen):
    pass

class KiwiFacts(Screen):
    pass

class MainPanel(GridLayout):
    pass

Builder.load_file("mainPanel.kv")

class Complex(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainPanel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Complex().run()
```

mainPanel.kv file:

```
#:include navigation.kv
#:include images.kv
#:include config.kv
#:include information.kv

<MainPanel>:
    cols:2
    Navigation:
    Images:
    Config:
    Information:
```

and information.kv file:

```
#: import  FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<Information>
    transition: FadeTransition()
    SlothFacts:
    KiwiFacts:

<SlothFacts>:
    name: "sloth"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "kiwi"
        text:"im sloth"

<KiwiFacts>:
    name: "kiwi"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "sloth"
        text:"im kiwi"
```

Thank you for answers in advance.

Comment: In your `information.kv`, references to `app.root` refer to the `MainPanel` instance, so setting the `current` attribute of a `MainPanel` has no effect (it is not a `ScreenManager`). Try changing `app.root.current` to `root.manager.current`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.